# Is there no XOR operator for booleans in golang?

Tags: go, operators, logical-operators, xor

Is there no XOR operator for booleans in golang?

I was trying to do something like `b1^b2` but it said it wasn't defined for booleans.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

There is not. Go does *not* provide [a *logical*](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Logical_operators) exclusive-OR operator (i.e. XOR over booleans) and [the *bitwise* XOR operator](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) applies only to integers.

However, [an exclusive-OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) can be rewritten in terms of other logical operators. When re-evaluation of the expressions (X and Y) is ignored,

```
X xor Y -> (X || Y) && !(X && Y)
```

Or, more trivially as Jsor pointed out,

```
X xor Y <-> X != Y
```

Comment: why isn't there one built in? I find it so weird.

Comment: While your definition of XOR is true, I'd go with `x != y`

Comment: @Jsor Doh. I miss the obvious far too often :| Updated.

Comment: You could say that Go *does* have an exclusive-or operator for `bool`, and it's spelled `!=`.

Comment: all good until you need something like `boolVar XOR boolFunc()`

Answer (score 127):

With booleans an xor is simply:

```
if boolA != boolB {

}
```

In this context `not equal to` performs the same function as `xor`: the statement can only be true if one of the booleans is true and one is false.

Comment: Clearly `(s == "test") != ( s == "not test")` does not work

Comment: @Adonis it works. XOR returns true if an only if only 1 of the 2 operands are true, and in your expression there are always a true and a false results, and `false != true` is true, which is the same as `false XOR true`

Answer (score 0):

Go support bitwise operators as of today. In case someone came here looking for the answer.