# Testing for existence on return value that could be concrete or nil

Tags: go

How would you write a test for a function that returns a value that could either be nil or a concrete value? I don't care about the actual value itself, I just care about whether the value has been returned or not.

```
type CustomType struct{}

func TestSomeFunc(t *testing.T) {
  case := map[string]struct {
    Input string
    Expected *CustomType // expected result
    Error error // expected error value
  } {
    "test case 1": 
      "input",
      &CustomType{}, // could be nil or a concrete value    
      nil,
    "test case 2": 
      "input",
      nil, // could be nil or a concrete value    
      ErrSomeError,
  }

  actual, err := SomeFunc(case.Input)
  if (actual != case.Expected) {
    t.Fatalf(...)
  }
}
```

and the function to be tested could look something like:

```
func SomeFunc(input string) (*CustomType, error) {
  foo, err := doSomething()
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err 
  }
  return foo, nil
}
```

I guess the logic I want is:

```
if ((case.Expected != nil && actual == nil) || 
    (case.Expected == nil && actual != nil)) {
    t.Fatalf(...)
}
```

Is there a better way of just asserting for existence rather than comparing concrete types?

Comment: Why can't you just use `if (case.Expected != actual)`? As a comment, as I may be missing the point.

Comment: @abligh that wouldn't work if they aren't equal and neither are nil

Comment: The condition or operator you want is the [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) (or its negation), which doesn't exist in Go for operands of type `bool`. For details / workaround, check out: [Is there no XOR operator for booleans in golang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025694/is-there-no-xor-operator-for-booleans-in-golang)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not much shorter than what you have, but I think what you want is for the test to pass only when `(case.Expected == nil) == (actual == nil)`, comparing the (`true` or `false`) results of two comparisons against `nil`. [Here's a short program demonstrating:](https://play.golang.org/p/ylwL8kjCXg)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    isNil, isNotNil, otherNotNil := []byte(nil), []byte{0}, []byte{1}
    fmt.Println("two different non-nil values\t", (otherNotNil == nil) == (isNotNil == nil))
    fmt.Println("a nil and a non-nil value\t", (isNil == nil) == (isNotNil == nil))
    fmt.Println("two nil values\t\t\t", (isNil == nil) == (isNil == nil))
}
```

As user icza points out, you can change the outer `==` into a `!=` (giving you something like `(actual == nil) != (expected == nil)`) to get `true` when there is a *mismatch* rather than when there is a match.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I think the `(isNotNil == nil) == (isNotNil == nil)` scenario would still trigger a test failure, even though it should pass since both the actual value and expected value are not nil.

Comment: @user34234 This will work, because if both are non-`nil`, then the expression evaluates to `(false) == (false)` which is `true`. This expression basically captures when the test should succeed. If you want the condition to fail, use `!=` in the middle of it: `(case.Expected == nil) != (actual == nil)`

Comment: @icza is right and I added to the demo program to show that the case you're talking about works.

Comment: (Also thanks to @icza's comment clarified that what I give at the top is a snippet returns `true` for a match and you can use != to return `true` for a mismatch.)

Comment: ok apparently my boolean logic is pretty weak. thanks to the both of you.